# WMPL and the Default Language

Tags: php, wordpress, translation, wpml

I have a Wordpress site which has been set up in English.

We have translated the site's entire contents into German using WPML. Now we have a requirement to set the language visitors will first see when they land on the site as German.

Is this possible?

I've read a horror story about having to totally reinstall the whole WP installation, and having to recode PHP so this is possible. Is this the only route to take?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Provide a link to and/or quote relevant content of the "horror story".

Comment: Can't you just set the default language to German? Under _WPML > Languages > Site Languages > Change default language_

Comment: Yes - Vicente you were right. I did do that but saw the original language. It as a mistake, the page had not been sent for translation, but I thought it had. Thanks for your replies.